# Is it possible to create new RCU schemas for an existing Domain?

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c, rcu

So basically I have a OSB domain, and the DB is going to be decommissioned and a new one will be created.
Is it possible to generate a new RCU on the new DB and then only replace the DB info on the the existing domain? Or should we migrate the existing RCU schemas from the old db to the new one?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Really depends how critical the data in the RCU tables is for your environment.  Is it a production environment?  You might have things like ESS triggers, or resequencer records in your current RCU tables that need to still exist in the new database.

If it's not production or there's no critical data in those RCU tables, you could just repoint the weblogic datasources to the new schemas in the new database.  I do this in my local weblogic domain environment which i use for development purposes.